# Twitter Follow Button not working as expected in Chrome 27 and below

Tags: html, css, twitter

So currently, the twitter follow button works as expected on my website in Chrome 28 and above. I noticed that it generates an `iframe` with these following attributes:

```
<iframe id="rufous-sandbox" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" allowfullscreen="true" style="position: absolute; visibility: hidden; display: none; width: 0px; height: 0px; padding: 0px; border: none;"></iframe>
```

This is added at the bottom of the body element; however, in Chrome 27 and below it adds it in between the head tag and the body tag. Also, it adds it without the `rufous-sandbox` ID and forces it to "push" the body element down so there is a large white space at the top.

In Chrome 27 and below:

```
<head>...</head>
<iframe>..</iframe>
<body>...</body>
```

[image: In Chrome 27]

How can I fix this? I tried adding the same styles to any `iframe` element, but that didn't work. The twitter script is in the `body` element, maybe I'm placing it in the wrong place ? Should it be in the `head` ?

Comment: Never seen this. Can you provide some example code that behaves like this? Or point to a website where this happens?

Comment: @MrLister http://fusionvr.space is my website

Comment: Whoa. I have Chromium 20 on my Windows XP VirtualBox, but the page makes it crash. "An unhandled win32 exception occurred in chrome.exe [3056]." This is after the iframe is inserted before the body. Oddly enough, neither the crash nor the problem in the question occurs with Chromium 6. (The latter one running in a Linux VB though.)

Comment: @MrLister That's odd, do you have any suggestions as to how I should go about fixing this ?

Comment: I don't know. Also I've been searching for Chrome 27, but it doesn't seem to be available for download any more...

Comment: I suppose I'll just try to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you go back to twitter and get the code for it, this is my code.....

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/GetBorealis" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="false">Follow Us!</a>
<script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Comment: Also **Please give me the link to your website so that I can test it out myself**

Comment: Ok sorry I didn't notice

Comment: This question is more than 6 months old, probably already solved without our help

Comment: Ok but i want to ask, can you help me with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40730702/how-to-make-this-object-move-faster/40730758?noredirect=1#comment68689134_40730758

Comment: Please avoid flooding topic; I don't have time to correctly answer question now, i'll take a look tomorrow if you still haven't got a good answer