# How to make this object move faster

Tags: javascript, html, keypress

In my code I make an object (A man sprite) move 1 pixel every time an arrow key is pressed. When you hold down the arrow key, the man is very very slow. I tried increasing the amount each time the key is pressed but that is not smooth enough. Can somebody tell me how I can make him move one pixel each time but move one pixel every 100 milliseconds? Thanks I appreciate the help.

```
    function moveLeft() {
    var newLeft = left - 1;
    left = newLeft;
    myElement.style.left = newLeft + 'px';

}
function moveUp() {
    var newTop = topStyle - 1;
    topStyle = newTop;
    myElement.style.top = newTop + 'px';

}
function moveRight() {
    var newLeft2 = left + 1;
    left = newLeft2;
    myElement.style.left = newLeft2 + 'px';

}
function moveDown() {
    var newTop2 = topStyle + 1;
    topStyle = newTop2
    myElement.style.top = newTop2 + 'px';
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add a functional case with the integrated snippet or with https://jsfiddle.net/  (we don't have your html base)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try it, i just re-write the whole code for you. now i use an interval for each 100 milliseconds

```js
var myElement = document.getElementById("character");

var move_left = false;
var move_up = false;
var move_right = false;
var move_down = false;

setInterval(function (){
 if (move_left) myElement.style.left = (getIntfromStyle(myElement.style.left) - 1) + 'px';
 if (move_up) myElement.style.top = (getIntfromStyle(myElement.style.top) - 1) + 'px';
 if (move_right) myElement.style.left = (getIntfromStyle(myElement.style.left) + 1) + 'px';
 if (move_down) myElement.style.top = (getIntfromStyle(myElement.style.top) + 1) + 'px';
}, 100);

// with this function, you dont need topStyle & left variables to store previous positions
// you can get current positioin easilysily
function getIntfromStyle(in_style) {
 return parseInt(in_style.replace('px', ''));
}

// i use keyboard to tell code when character should be moved and when must stop
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    switch(e.which || e.keyCode) {
  case 37: // left
   move_left = true;
   break;
        case 38: // up
   move_up = true;
   break;
        case 39: // right
   move_right = true;
   break;
        case 40: // down
   move_down = true;
   break;
        default: return; // exit this handler for other keys
 }
 e.preventDefault(); // prevent the default action (scroll / move caret)
}

document.onkeyup = function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    switch(e.which || e.keyCode) {
  case 37: // left
   move_left = false;
   break;
        case 38: // up
   move_up = false;
   break;
        case 39: // right
   move_right = false;
   break;
        case 40: // down
   move_down = false;
   break;
 }
}
```

```html
<div id="character"  style="background:red;width:20px;height:20px;position:fixed;display:block;left:0;top:0"></div>
```

Comment: so the variable would be `var speed = const speed = 5;`

Comment: @T.Bragg what do you mean by `var speed = const speed = 5;`  i used const instead var because **speed** value could not change and only defined once, but you can simply change the `const` to `var`

Comment: I know, I thought I was wrong and I tried that but it didn't work

Comment: All that this does is increment the object by 5 now

Comment: how would i make it move smoothly though

Comment: @T.Bragg, use a shorter interval, i used 100, you may use 30 instead, why dont you accept it yet?